# Generic robot parameter loading for multiple robots

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, yaml, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have a package which subscribes to multiple robots. I wish to use a more generic solution where I use bind to generate the callback for each robot listed in the .yaml file.  Example how I would like to parse the parameters:

```
Robot_parameters:
 name: Robot1 
  scan_topic_name: r2/scan
  sensor_frame: r1/lidar_link
  base_link_frame: r1/base_link

 name: Robot2
  scan_topic_name: r2/scan
  sensor_frame: r2/lidar_link
  base_link_frame: r2/base_link
 .
 .
 .
 name: a_robot_name
  scan_topic_name: topic_name
  sensor_frame: some_frame_name
  base_link_frame: another_frame_name
```

Looking for a good method to load these files. I can do this no-problem by loading a normal .txt file but I wanna do this in a "ROS" fashion by keeping it on the parameter server somehow. I wish to iterate over these parameters and bind these variables to callbacks for the N amount of robots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347307/generic-robot-parameter-loading-for-multiple-robots./) by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-03-23**:
[I believe this might be the answer to my question](https://answers.ros.org/question/189299/getting-hierarchy-level-of-yaml-parameter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Made a functioning example:](https://github.com/bob-ROS/list_parameter_example)

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <XmlRpcValue.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void callback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg, std::string base_frame, std::string sensor_frame)
{
  ROS_INFO("Recieved scan on callback");
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Base frame is: " << base_frame.c_str());
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sensor frame is: " <<sensor_frame.c_str());
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ){
 ros::init(argc, argv, "list_parameter_example_node");
 ros::NodeHandle nh;

 XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue robots;
 nh.getParam("robots", robots);
 ROS_ASSERT("failed to load parameters!" && robots.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct);
 std::vector<ros::Subscriber> sub_vector;
 for(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::ValueStruct::const_iterator it = robots.begin(); it != robots.end(); ++it) {
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("Found robots: " << (std::string)(it->first) << " ==> " << robots[it->first]);
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("scan_topic_name: " << robots[it->first]["scan_topic_name"]);
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("Base_frame: " << robots[it->first]["base_frame"]);
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("sensor_frame: " << robots[it->first]["sensor_frame"]);

   sub_vector.push_back(nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(robots[it->first]["scan_topic_name"],1, boost::bind(&callback, _1, robots[it->first]["base_frame"],robots[it->first]["sensor_frame"])));

 }

 ros::Rate loop_rate(5); //5Hz

 while(ros::ok())
 {
   ros::spinOnce();
   loop_rate.sleep();
 }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0